# Fancybox is not a function in prestashop 1.6

Tags: jquery, fancybox, prestashop

I have very strange problem. I have two online shop. Both are on the default theme. Both has the same module which allow to add user email to newsletter by display pop-up. In the second one the webiste doesn't load

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
```

And of course in conole I have

```
$(...).fancybox is not a function
```

The question is. How to check why in one website everything is fine and in the second is problem. The same themes. The same module. Different results.

Kind regards

Comment: Most likely you have included jQuery multiple times and therefore lost previously included plugins.

Comment: In both shop I have default module. Maybe I ask in another way. How to load fancybox in prestashop ?

Comment: There is no official module for PrestaShop. You can include it just like for any other website - 1) include two files (js and css); 2) add `data-fancybox` attribute for your links; 3) customize.

Answer (score 1):

Fancybox may be loaded by some other additional module installed in one PS.1.6 shop which is not present in second PS.1.6 It´s not about theme.
For your module you have to make php override to "hookDisplayHeader" with:

```
$this->context->controller->addJqueryPlugin('fancybox');
```

Then you can use link like

```
<a href="{$link->getCMSLink(1)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}?content_only=1" class="iframe">
```

and script

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('a.iframe').fancybox({
        'type' : 'iframe',
        'width':500,
        'height':900
    });
</script>
{/literal}
```

in your .tpl file